# SSH Tunnel out of Docker container

Tags: docker, flask, ssh

I am working on a python flask app and have to tunnel into different machines to access our databases. When run the application without docker I have no problem and everything works fine. But when I run the application in a container I face the error:

```
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

My Dockerfile for my image is:

```
FROM python:3.11.7-slim
WORKDIR /monitoring
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y openssh-client
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./.env ./.env
EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP=app/main.py
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Do I have to take further steps to make the application inside the container able to SSH tunnel outside? I have looked on the internet and found no resource on an issue like that. Do you have an idea where I should look?

After further investigation I found this (I passed a logger to the SSHTunnelForwarder):

```
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.0)
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

Which makes no sense since I am providing the same ssh private key and it works outside of the container.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for us to diagnose the problem. You've mentioned `paramiko`, but you're also installing the `openssh-client` package in your image. There's nothing here that shows how you're exposing the private key to your container, nor is there a [mcve] with code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am passing the private key as environment variable in the .env file. I will work on a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you, but what I understood is that your app uses ssh-key/s to do some tasks, but the can't do it in with the same app inside the container, this is due to ssh-key file/s don't exist inside the container, copy them to container if you run that on localhost or mount the directory of key/s to ~/.ssh/ inside container.